# Self join to get friends of friend in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have a `friends` table as below

```
+------+--------+
| Name | Friend |
+------+--------+
| A    | B      |
| B    | C      |
| D    | B      |
| D    | C      |
| A    | E      |
| E    | Z      |
+------+--------+
```

I want to get friend of friend for each friend.

For that I wrote a below query

```
SELECT a.Name as Friend,b.Friend as FOF
FROM friends a
JOIN friends b
ON a.Friend = b.Name
```

With that query I am getting *partially* correct output as below

```
+--------+-----+
| Friend | FOF |
+--------+-----+
| A      | C   |
| D      | C   |
| A      | Z   |
+--------+-----+
```

In the output I am getting `C` as `friend of friend` of `D`.(Because `D` is friend of `B` and `C` is friend of `B`) but `C` is also a direct friend of `D`.

So I want to update the query to exclude `friend of friend` which are also direct friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is to add `not exists`:

```
SELECT f1.Name as Friend, f2.Friend as FOF
FROM friends f1 JOIN
     friends f2
     ON f1.Friend = f2.Name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM friends f
                  WHERE f.Name = f1.Name and f.Friend = f2.Friend
                 );
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic of correlated subquery ?

Comment: @sql_learner It's easier to read had SQL Server has tuple support:

`where (a.Name, b.Friend) not in (select df.Name, df.Friend from friends df)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

How the query would like if SQL Server has tuple support:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/14aec6/1

```
SELECT a.Name as Friend,b.Friend as FOF
FROM friends a
JOIN friends b ON a.Friend = b.Name 

-- exclude fof if it is already in direct friends
WHERE (a.Name, b.Friend) NOT IN (select df.Name, df.Friend from friends df)
```

Output:

```
| friend | fof |
|--------|-----|
|      A |   C |
|      A |   Z |
```

You can [simplify](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a5c08/13) the query by removing the alias from derived table since derived table don't normally need to correlate with outer query. To wit:

```
WHERE (a.Name, b.Friend) NOT IN (select Name, Friend from friends)
```

Since SQL Server don't support that yet, you can use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` instead. See Gordon's answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

You just need you filter out those result who are direct friend as well.

**Method:1** using **Not Exist**

```
SELECT f1.Name as Friend, f2.Friend as FOF
FROM friends f1 JOIN
     friends f2
     ON f1.Friend = f2.Name
WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM friends f WHERE f.Name = f1.Name and f.Friend = f2.Friend);
```

**Method:2** using **Not IN**

```
SELECT f1.Name as Friend, f2.Friend as FOF
FROM friends f1 JOIN
     friends f2
     ON f1.Friend = f2.Name
WHERE (f1.name,f2.friend) not in  (SELECT f3.name,f3.Friend from friends f3);
```

Comment: Direct friends D and C, are still not excluded. See your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a5c08/5

Comment: Yes it's working correctly. But long before your edit, Gordon already have an answer. Which incidentally your method is same as his. And your second method, is same as mine :)

Comment: Anyway, I don't see this problem can be solved in any other ways. It's very likely that we will all come up with same answers anyhow. Anyway, it's good that you solved it too

Comment: Thanks for the answer !